# Excel VBA change button size and location

Tags: excel, vba, location, size

How do I change a button size and location on an excel sheet?

Comment: The only thing that I found is adding a button. I also found ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1") but did not get it to work.

Comment: Why was this post down-voted? If you are going to down-vote someone, please explain your reasoning. That's why we're all here: to learn from each other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there with `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1")`

If you `dim` a variable as `Shape` and assign the button to it, you can use intellisence to explore the available properties.   From there you will find `.Height`, `.Width`, `.Left`, `.Top`

```
Dim btn As Shape
Set btn = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1")
btn.Height = 50
btn.Width = 100
```

Comment: The units of the height and width measurement are in points. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.left?source=recommendations

Comment: More details about points, twips and millimetres https://davetallett26.github.io/makeform.html

Answer (score 0):

Steven, to learn basic VBA in Excel, I recommend experimenting with the **Record Macro** option.  It's location varies depending on your version of Excel (In 2007, you need to activate the Developer tab in your ribbon).

With this button turned on, use the standard menus to do whatever you wanted to do in the first place (in this case, make a custom sized button).  Then stop the recording and look at the auto-generated code you just made.

Comment: Excellent tip, but all I see on record macro is .ScaleWidth and not .Width

Comment: You are correct.  I had to try it for myself.  For some reason the macro recorder only records commands for scaling the button's size.  It doesn't record absolute changes in the size.  Please use @chris neilsen's answer.